# How do I sync iCloud iWork documents with Lion?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, icloud, iwork

I have been using my iPad with Numbers and would like to be able to just open them up on my Mac with Lion. I can not figure out how to connect/sync to iCloud documents. I have checked iCloud documents for syncing, but my documents don't appear on my Mac. 
I have even set up my mobile documents folder on the desktop. I can drag files to the iCloud that way, but then I can not open them from that folder. Frustrating.

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30450/once-ios-files-are-backed-up-to-icloud-can-you-access-them-programmatically

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Macintosh does not (yet) support complete iCloud synchronization for documents. We can only hope that Apple will implement this at some point soon.

In the mean time, go to http://www.icloud.com/ and sign in. You can drag documents to and from the appropriate section on your computer, and it'll work with your iPad. There's still [another bug](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37364/why-wont-icloud-let-me-download-pages-documents-uploaded-from-a-computer), which involves Mac > Mac syncing, but as long as you just do iPad > Mac or Mac > iPad, it'll work fine. :)

Also, there is a folder located at `~/Library/Mobile Documents/` which contains your iCloud-enabled apps' data. This includes the iWork suite, but unfortunately iWork documents aren't saved as the normal filetypes (e.g. ".pages"), so they can't be opened on their own.

Comment: Update to this: the upcoming OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) sounds like [it will add the desired capability to iWork](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/features.html#icloud) et. al.

Answer (score 3):

The following works on Lion 10.7.4:

Warning! If you don't know what you are doing, then you probably shouldn't be doing this. You take all responsibility for nuking your own iCloud data.

- As usual, make sure you have iCloud setup for your user and enable Documents & Data sync.

Execute next steps from Terminal (`/Applications/Utilities/Terminal`):

- run: `sudo nano /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.ubd.plist` - change `RunAtLoad` from `false` to `true`
- run: `defaults write com.apple.ubd kUBSyncEnabledKey -bool true`

At this point, ubd needs to be restarted..

- run: `launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.ubd.plist`
- run: `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.ubd.plist`

now `~/Library/Mobile Documents` should be synced up.

If for some reason it's still not syncing after step 4, try logging out and back in.

Comment: Confirmed this works.