# Why won't iCloud let me download Pages documents uploaded from a computer?

Tags: ios, icloud, data-transfer, pages, iwork

It often happens that I create a Pages document on my home laptop, upload it to iCloud, then want to download it from iCloud at school. For some reason, iCloud doesn't support this—I need to, at some point between those two steps, open Pages on an iOS device synched with my iCloud account. Then it'll work fine.

I assume this has something to do with a preview being included in the file, as in iCloud it shows up as a generic .pages document rather than the customary document preview image thing, but I can't see why. Pages does include a preview in its saves, and "Include preview in document by default" is checked.

What's happening, and is there any way I can get around it without use of an iPad or iPhone?

Comment: Use Dropbox. It can support this and much more. It's not an Apple product, but works great with Macs, iPads, and iPhone. You can get a free account here: http://www.dropbox.com/

Comment: How are you downloading it? from iCloud.com or automatilcy through your Apple ID onto the computer?

Comment: Well, there's no way to automatically download iWork documents to the computer, so iCloud.com. Or did you mean the Mobile Documents folder?

Comment: I am not sure why, but I always have to open files uploaded from a computer on my iPad at least once before I can download them from iCloud.

Comment: What I mean is are you going to iCloud.com to download teh docs, or are you just opening Pages and finind them in recent?

Comment: you have to open the document with the appropriate iWork for iOS app on an iOS 5 device before it becomes available for download from icloud.com on a computer

Comment: I'm going to iCloud.com.

Comment: That's exactly what I've already said, and is therefore completely redundant and unhelpful.

Comment: I've already pointed that out, thank you. I'm wondering "why?" and "how can I skip the iPad step?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same things happens to me. After some digging around I found this [from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2704):

> Important:   You cannot download a document from icloud.com to your Mac or Windows computer until the document has been opened on an iOS device.

My guess is that this is a symptom of iCloud's "work in progress" status, and that this functionality will eventually be there. Considering that you are only asking to download the exact same file that you uploaded, though, it is a pretty silly restriction.

#### Update:

For me, the behavior has recently changed. Now if you upload a file from your computer to icloud.com, you can download *the original file* to any computer from icloud.com. You still must download the document to an iOS device before you can download the file as a PDF or other format.

Answer (score 2):

The format used by iOS Pages is slightly different to the format used by OSX Pages. (who knows why Apple though this was clever?)

As the OSX iWork apps don't have iCloud document sync built in, iCloud.com primarily works with iOS devices.

But with Mountain Lion, it looks like at least the file formats will become interchangeable, if not the same, as the iWork document sync appears to built into the OS itself, rather than just the iWork apps (probably the reason why the iWork apps still dont' have iCloud built in)

You are pretty much stuck (I say stuck, in many ways better) with services like DropBox, in the hope that iCloud/com is vastly improved for Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

I have reda somewhwere that the files actually sync to a folder on the Mac if you have iCloud enabled. But I don't know if you can open those files in iWork on the Mac.

Comment: It's the Mobile Documents folder, in ~/Library/. I'll try that.

Comment: It didn't work. But thanks! (The file's missing an internal index file of some sort, which I can't locate.)

Comment: Sorry about that. Apple insider talks about the Lion 10.7.3 beta that it should focus on iCloud doc storage. So there might be hope. [Article](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/12/20/apple_seeds_new_os_x_lion_10_7_3_build_to_developers.html)