# Can't download DOC or PDF from iCloud web app

Tags: pages, iwork, icloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why won’t iCloud let me download Pages documents uploaded from a computer?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37364/why-wont-icloud-let-me-download-pages-documents-uploaded-from-a-computer)

I recently updated Pages, Numbers and Keynote to the latest versions, and my OS to Mountan Lion. I went ahead and tried the "documents in the cloud" feature by saving a Pages document on iCloud.

As a long time user of the now shut-down iWork.com beta, I was surprised and pleased to find the following menu on the iCloud.com iWork web app:

[image: Download Pages document in multiple fornats]

**iCloud appears to allow download in other formats but the options are disabled for some reason.
How can I enable this document to be downloaded in PDF and WORD formats?**

Comment: Err, what exactly is your question?

Comment: If anyone knows why this might be and how to solve it.

Comment: I chose to turn this into a distinct, clear question, instead of just closing it. It's your lucky day.

Comment: Meh, sorry. Thought on giving the most info I could, cause it could potentially be useful... like the info on how I put the documents there and such. Good edits though man: much clearer. Keep up the good work!

Comment: I would love to find out myself, how to enable the pdf and word format when downloading from icloud. I would like to download PDF versions of my download, when I am away from my mac!

Comment: definitely! It would make things much more convenient, and basically remove the need for any exporting and mailing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be enabled after having opened on iOS, my thinking is that it's something to do with the message you get when opening an iOS version of something created on OS X, which lets you open copy or open, saying that it may look different. Anyway, after opening on iOS, you can download from iCloud.com in all three formats, however, after saving or editing on OS X the PDF and DOC options are blanked again.

Comment: Oh, bummer. I don't have access to an iOS version of the iWork apps so I can't really check this out, but it sounds pretty reasonable. After all, it seems like Apple has been focusing more on the iOS iWork apps. It wouldn't surprise me if this is some sort of feature available only on the mobile platform. Though I can't confirm it I'll mark it as correct, "unless proven otherwise". (: