# Accessing iCloud "Mobile Documents" on latest Lion

Tags: macos, ipad, mac, icloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sync iCloud iWork documents with Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37059/how-do-i-sync-icloud-iwork-documents-with-lion)

It used to be (for example, as documented here: [How do I sync iCloud iWork documents with Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37059/how-do-i-sync-icloud-iwork-documents-with-lion)) that you could access iCloud documents from the **~/Library/Mobile Documents** folder. However, it appears that in the latest updates to Lion (I am using 10.7.3) that this functionality has been removed/disabled. FWIW, I'm trying to access the documents on my iPad stored in GoodReader from my Mac.

Does anyone know any workarounds or alternative approaches for this?

Comment: Are you looking for the same thing as this question asks? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30450/once-ios-files-are-backed-up-to-icloud-can-you-access-them-programmatically

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "removed/disabled"? I'm still able to see the folder, with current data…

Comment: I mean that it isn't there. (FWIW, I "started" with Lion - I haven't been through any upgrades).

Comment: @Timothy, not exactly. He is asking for a programmatic API. I'd just like them to appear in a folder or suchlike...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a solution here that doesnt require any special apps/tricks:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/63026/28551

Comment: Confirmed that this works.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a 10.7.3 system to test on, but on 10.7.4 the folder ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents exists and is populated with whatever cloud documents I have from iOS.

Perhaps something else is preventing you from getting the files. Have you tried turning of iCloud Documents in your user account and making a new user on the Mac.

If the folder appears on the new user when you turn on document syncing - perhaps turning it off and then on the first account will nudge things. Worst case, you will be narrowing it down to an account or a software issue with these steps.

Comment: Upgrade from 10.7.3 to 10.7.4 doesn't change anything.

Comment: I've checked 3 different iCloud accounts with three different Mac running Lion and the documents iOS stores in the cloud end up on each Mac. This is supposed to work, does work for most, so you might have to get Apple to look at things if no one else has suggestions. Have you tried another Mac or another user account? Those help isolate an issue on your Mac. In fact, what worked to add syncing before it was officially rolled out could be the cause of your issues now that iCloud is supposed to sync the documents with no poking or prodding required.